# If each term in a sum converges, does the infinite sum converge too?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Let $S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n(x)$ where the real valued terms satisfy
$s_n(x) \to s_n$ as $x \to \infty$ for each $n$.

Suppose that $S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n< \infty$.

Does it follow that $S(x) \to S$ as $x \to \infty$?

I really do not recall any theorems... please point out !!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not true. Consider $s_n(x) = 1/x$. We have $\lim_{x \to \infty} s_n(x) = 0 = t_n$. Clearly, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} t_n =0 < \infty$. However,
$$S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n s_n(x) = \dfrac{n}x$$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n(x)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: So in your example $S(x)$ is infinite. If it is assumed finite, for every $x$, is it true?

Comment: I hadn't posted my answer yet when I saw yours; apparently we thought of exactly the same thing.

Comment: The question actually assumes that $S(x)$ exists this means that $\lim_{n\to \infty} S_n(x)$ exists (is an assumption in the question otherwise the written sum would not have any sense.

Comment: @Elaqqad Just noticed that, deleting my comment.

Answer (score 9):

A convergent example:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{x+n} + \frac{1}{x-n} \right) = \pi\cot{\pi x}-\frac{1}{x}, $$
and the convergence is uniform on closed intervals not containing integer points.

Clearly every function in the sum tends to $0$ as $x \to \infty$, but the entire sum does not.

---

**Edit:** An even better example, perhaps: set
$$ s_n(x) = \chi_{[n,n+1)}(x), $$
i.e. $1$ for $n \leqslant x < n+1$, and $0$ otherwise. It is clear that $s_n(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, but it is also clear, since every real number is in precisely one interval of the form $[n,n+1)$, that
$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} s_n(x)=1. $$

Comment: This is good counterexample

Comment: It is tricky, because the $s_n(x)$ are not defined for all $x\in\mathbb R$, so you have to be careful about saying $s_n(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Well, no, since no uniformity is demanded, and $s_n(x)$ is defined, for fixed $n$, for all sufficiently large $x$, it is easy to show that there exists an $N$, dependent on $n$, such that $|s_n(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x>N$.

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, this is not true in general.  But there is a very important case where it is true: power series.  Abel's theorem says that  if $S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ and $S(1)$ converges, then $\lim_{x \to 1-} S(x) = S(1)$.

Since you're interested in $x \to \infty$, this will require a transformation to apply to your case.  Thus take some increasing function $g: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ such that $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = L > 0$ exists, and a series of the form
$S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n g(x)^n$.  If $S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n L^n$ converges, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} S(x) = S$.

Comment: @Elaqqad I agree it was my intention that the infinite sum denoted by $S(x)$ was finite but I gueess I should have written it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the instructive answer

Answer (score 3):

You can also find examples in which all series are convergent, yet you cannot pass to the limit. Try this: 
$$
s_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
1, & n=[x] \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Here $[x]$ is the [floor or ceiling function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) (choose the one you like most, it does not matter).

To guarantee that you can pass to the limit under the sum you need some extra properties on the convergence of $s_n(x)$.

Comment: What properties do you need? uniform convergence?

Comment: @RealMax: Exactly. Uniform convergence of the series $\sum_n s_n(x)$ with respect to $x$ suffices to guarantee that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sum_n s_n(x)=\sum_n \lim_{x\to\infty}s_n(x).$

Comment: @Elaqqad: I am afraid I don't understand. Here the limit function $s(x)$ is identically zero, so its sum is $0$. However, the sum $\sum_n s_n(x)$ is $1$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Elaqqad Why does $S(x)$ not exist here? $S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n(x)=1$ if $x\in\mathbb N$, $0$ if not.

Comment: @Laertes I'm sorry the limit exists here

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks,. I guess you mean uniform convergence in $m$ of the sequence $p_m = \sum_{n=1}^m s_n(x).$

Comment: @RealMax: Yes of course.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Let $s_n(x)=\frac 1x$, $s_n=0$. Then $S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n$ trivially converges. However, $S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n(x)$ is clearly divergent, since the summand is a constant (with respect to $n$) greater than $0$.

Comment: What about $lim_{x\to\infty} S(x)$? Can we pass that limit through the sum since it is with respect to a different variable than the sum?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another condition which is sufficient to allow you to interchange the limit and the sum.
Let
$$
  S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty s_n(x),
  \qquad
  S_m = \sum_{n=1}^m \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} s_n(x) = \sum_{n=1}^m s_n,
  \qquad
  S_m(x) = \sum_{n=1}^m s_n(x).
$$
We know that $S_m \rightarrow S$ and want to know if also $S(x) \rightarrow S$.

If each of your functions is bounded by some number,
$$
  | s_n(x) | \le g_n \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb N
$$
and the $(g_n)$ are summable, i.e.,
$$
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty g_n < \infty,
$$
then we have
$$
 |S(x) - S_m(x)| = \left| \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty s_n(x) \right| \le \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty g_n,
$$
and clearly the right-hand side converges to zero uniformly in $x$ (since it doesn't even depend on $x$). In other words,
$$
  S_m(x) \rightarrow S(x) \quad \text{uniformly in } x.
$$
Therefore, we are allowed to exchange the sum and the limit and obtain
$$
  \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} S(x)
  = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} S_m(x)
  = \lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} S_m(x)
  = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} S_m.
$$

This is the principle of [dominated convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Comment: This is a good answer, making it clear that the famous Weierstrass's M-test is part of the principle of dominated convergence. (I liked the use of the word "principle" instead of "theorem" here).